# Memory is not releasing on the cleaning of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I am loading more Resources (Images & videos) in a UIView which is added as a child of UIViewController as I am cleaning the UIView as

`UIView *get_mainview = (UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];

    //IMP code to remove sbview
        [[get_mainview subviews]
     makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];`
The **get_mainview** clearing it's objects but memory is not releasing . if i am writing

```
[get_mainview release];
```

I am getting error because i am adding further other chield to **get_mainview** 
Note - I am not using ARC.
I am working on Xcode 5.0
Please helpme how to release memory .

Comment: Try to nslog retain count of each object in you class. Then you may know which object is not going to release.

Comment: Actually the parent element is get_mainview if I am cleaning it, so it will remove all object of it child & associate child's right?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `[get_mainview removeFromSuperview]` instead of `release` so that its superview will reduce the reference count by 1.

Don't call `release` on that view if you are not retaining it anywhere, just removing it from the superview should do the trick.

Hope that helps!

Comment: if I am doing [get_mainview removeFromSuperview] & again adding something else in get_mainview, it's not showing the child element .

Comment: @anupammishra If you want to reuse the `get_mainview` instance then you should have it as a ivar/property and `retain` it until required. When you do this, then in the `dealloc` method of your view controller  you should release it.

Comment: @anupammishra I hope you have basic understanding of memory management in ObjectiveC. If not, i'd suggest you read that first.

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that you are correctly releasing the objects, then check if the images you load aren't loaded with `[UIImage imageNamed:@""];` because this method caches the images for later use.

Comment: I am using RNCryptor to encrypt & decrypt the images in memory. as images are decrypted it's using like this UIImage *image=(decrypted image in memory);  [uiimageview setImage:image];

Comment: Okay, so that's not the case. I will just keep the answer, thou.